# Efficiently generating one token at a time with huggingface (.generate() does a lot of reprocessing?)

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model

If i want to calculate one token at a time so I can do postprocessing for each token, then I call .generate() with max token = 1.
But this means for every token, I am reprocessnig the entire previous input (prompt and all)!
Is there a way to save state or cache so I only process the additional information instead of reprocessing all previous information?

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by `re-processing`? Are you referring to the beam-search changes made when the generation is set to more than 1 max_token? If so, then changing the inference from beam_search to a greedy one, e.g. by setting beam_size=1 would emulate "generating one token at a time"

Comment: Also, please do help to (i) re-phrase the question with some context to your question, and (ii) the code you've tried to produce the output, (iii) what is the current output you are seeing and (iv) what is the expected output you are trying to achieve and possibly (v) what is the motivation for trying to generate one token at a time? Is it just a UI thing where you want to print out words one at a time? Or do you want the model to generate one at a time without considering impact of future words?